# How to get only a specific "row" of a string?

Tags: grep, ps

I'm trying to get the lowest PID of a specific process of a user. In my case the user is named as `content` and the specific process is named as `gnome-terminal-server`. I'm using the below command to get the desired output.

`command`

```
ps -eF|grep -F 'gnome-terminal-server'|grep -E '^content'|head -n1
```

`output`

```
content     1758    1659  0 116290 39408  0 09:07 ?        00:00:01 /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
```

But I fail to format the output accordingly. I only want to get the PID no. `1758`, so that I may assign it to a variable, like `TERMINAL_PID=1758`, for further processing.

So how do I format the `output` in bash/sh to get only the 2nd row (`1758`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find a line, you use `grep`, which is ok.

In order to show a part of that line, you can use `cut` or `awk`. If you choose for `awk`, you can add this to your command:

```
| awk '{print $2}'
```

(Show the second column)

So, your command becomes:

```
ps -eF | grep -F 'gnome-terminal-server' | grep -E '^content' | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Wow thank you, I didn't knew about this `awk` :) Sorry if my questions was a bit silly, but I had no idea what I should search for. Thank you

Comment: Don't worry. Just know that `cut` is just a simple command for cutting a line in pieces, while `awk` is much more than that: you can do text formatting, calculations, ... with it: you're just getting started :-)